# Correct very blurry text in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is is possible to correct very blurry text with Photoshop? In a hurry, I took this picture, but the text is pretty much unreadable.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is almost possible using a manual shake reduction adjustment, but not quite.  Enough to tell it's in German at least. Then again, if you are German, you may be able to read it better than me!

[image: Example of Shake Reduction]

If you want a better image, best to take it again, but make sure you use something to help you steady the camera. I'm afraid Photoshop can't work miracles on blurry images.

Comment: May I ask which settings you used? Thanks!

Comment: First I did a levels adjustment to increase the contrast, then I used the shake reduction filter, and created the path manually in the direction of the camera shake, then reduced the sliders so there was not too much smoothing or artefact reduction.